# Struggling to output PHP array as unordered HTML list

Tags: php, html

Apologies as this is probably very basic. I have created a `SELECT` query and have (I think) stored the data retrieved as an array.

By myself I have been able to use `printf` to output selected items from the array but I want to output the values in a more structured way, as an unordered list in HTML. It's going to be a list of links. `anchor` corresponds to the link name column in my MySQL table and `link` corresponds to the url column, to be output as, e.g 
`<li><a href="link">anchor</a></li>`

This is as far as I have got. I know I need a `for` loop but the demos I've copied keep failing.

Very grateful for any pointers from kind people. Backend is new to me.

```html
<?php
$server = "localhost";  
$username = "blah";
$password = "blahblah";
$database = "blah_db";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}       

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT  anchor, link FROM footerLinks");
   

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    printf("Anchor: %s  Link: %s ", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: `<li><a href="link">anchor</a></li>` for this `echo '<li><a href="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</a></li>';` put this in while loop then check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much to change in your code. Add `<ul>` and `</ul>` around the `while` loop. Change the pattern to `<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>`. And swap `$row[0], $row[1]` to `$row[1], $row[0]`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT  anchor, link FROM footerLinks");

echo '<ul>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    printf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', $row[1], $row[0]); 
}
echo '</ul>';
```

I would though use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` instead of `MYSQLI_NUM` (which is considered bad practice), and also use the object oriented style for mysqli functions:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT  anchor, link FROM footerLinks");

echo '<ul>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', $row['link'], $row['anchor']); 
}
echo '</ul>';
```